# Angular 4 ng build not loading raw loader

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I did an ng eject on my angular 4 app and added the following to the resulting webpack.config.js (Needed it for i18n)

```
{
    "test": /\.xlf$/,
    "loader": 'raw-loader'     
}
```

But when i do `ng build --base-href --prod`, it complains about not having the appropriate loader for .xlf files.

> WARNING in ./src/app/locale/messages.es.xlf
>   Module parse failed: /src/app/locale/messages.es.xlf Unexpected token (1:0)
>   You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

It seems that ng build is not using the ejected webpack.config.js

Comment: I believe the problem is that you're still using the command `ng build` - which uses the Angular CLI rather than webpack to build the app. When you eject, Angular tells you to use `npm run start` instead, which uses the webpack command / config